# AddFilter with ID/NAME

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

is possible with addFilter get a query with ID/Name of my Entity?

I try:

```
query.addFilter("_key_", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,18);

query.addFilter("id", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,18);

query.addFilter("ID/Name", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,18);
```

I saw responses from other users like [How to retrieve Google Appengine Objects by id (Long value)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938967/how-to-retrieve-google-appengine-objects-by-id-long-value), but not in addFilter.
Is possible?

Thx

Comment: Ever got an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key field is `__key__`, but I would recommend using [datastore.get](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#get%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29) instead of a query for getting an entity by key.